# Enforcing parameter name consistency

Tags: java, interface

In the following trivial example an interface is created, with a method & parameter name bar.

The following implementation subtly changes this legally by specifying zoo.

```java
    public class Query {

      public interface MyInterface {
        public void foo(int bar);
      }

      public class Thing implements MyInterface {
        @Override
        public void foo(int zoo) { }   
      }

      public Query() { }

      public static void main(String[] args) { }

    }
```

How can i force the parameter name to conform to what was specified in `MyInterface` (`bar` **not** `zoo`)?

Ideally i am looking for a compiler option or similar that would throw a warning or error.

Comment: You can not. The only way would be plugins or frameworks that check the code itself. But Java itself will always allow this. There are even more things an interface implementing class is allowed to change, like method visibility and final etc. But why would you care? bar or zoo, its only a name locally known to the methid itself. So nobody should care for it.

Comment: In order to give an appropriate answer we need to know your motivation for this. Maybe there are better options.

Comment: For context i have an interface that has many implementations, I would like them all to be strictly consistent as the meaning has changed subtly over time.

Comment: But why? You dont need the name, only the guy who implements the method needs to care about the name, since it is only known to the implementing method. What do you mean by "the meaning has changed"? Are you modifying an interface that is already implemented by customers in a way that its logic changes? Well, this sounds like a bad thing to do in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On compiler level (e.g. javac) - **you cannot**, the [method signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) is being create only from the method name and parameters **types** so the names and return type are basically ignored

The only you can do is to write your own syntax rule for tools like SonarQube but as far as I understand it won't be suitable for you.

Seems that you want to create some library [code serializing?] and force user to use proper parameter naming - that means that you would need to force him to use specific tool also

Comment: This is as i suspected. Thanks all for your help.